# Variation Subscription Products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, subscription

I have **"Pricing" page** in my **WordPress** Project, where I retrieve **WooCommerce Subscription Products** and show all features, etc. And, I have button for each product which redirects to checkout page with the **Product Variation** chosen (which is monthly / yearly from attribute called "billing_period") **added to the cart**. But, **when I enter test credit card** information like the following, it's saying:

```
Error processing checkout. Please try again.
```

I **tried** with the **following** test credit **cards**, but it **didn't work**:

```
Card number: 4242 4242 4242 4242 & 4111 1111 1111 1111
Exp. Date: 02 / 27 (should be any date in the future)
CVC: 999 (any three digits)
```

Is it something to do with variations? Or the way I'm redirecting to checkout isn't quite right? Can you help with this issue please...?